# How change my editer's linter configuration ATOM .jshintrc setting where do i put in

Tags: jshint, atom-editor

I want set my JSHint on Atom editor. Where do I put .jshintrc file in Atom?

here is my .jshintrc file

```
"globals": {
    "$": false,
    "jQuery": false
}
```

I'm using the [linter-jshint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-jshint) package.

I try to put the code to Atom's config.cson but it doesn't seem to work.

```
'global':
  'editor':
    'showIndentGuide': true
    'tabLength': 4
    'fontSize': 14
    'invisibles': {}
  'exception-reporting':
    'userId': '807682f7-4468-e7ec-677e-6968e54390c6'
  'welcome':
    'showOnStartup': false
  'core':
    'themes': [
      'atom-dark-ui'
      'monokai'
    ]
  'linter':
    'showAllErrorsInStatusBar': true
    'linter-jshint':
      'jshintExecutablePath': 'Yosemite/Users/hyunahn/.atom/packages'
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://atom.io/packages/atom-jshint

Comment: I'm using is this https://atom.io/packages/linter-jshint

Comment: I got it!  "You should have a .jshintrc file in your projects’ root folder."  Thank you guys i solve them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the documentation states](https://atom.io/packages/atom-jshint), you can have a `.jshintrc` file in the root or any subfolder:

> "Supports custom .jshintrc file in project root and all parent directories"

Comment: How would I do this globally in Atom (so I don't have to put one in each project folder)?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can do it globally

Answer (score 2):

Like the previously responder noted, you can put the `.jshintrc` file at the root of your project directory.

For reader's who may not know completely what a .jshintrc file is:
It's a configuration file with rules that tells JSHint which rules to enforce. *JSHint will start looking for this file in the same directory as the file that's being linted. If not found, it will move one level up the directory tree all the way up to the filesystem root.*

[Here](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintrc) is a standard .jshintrc file you can copy-paste and modify to your needs.